# Adding a UIButton to view after video gets completed playing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, uibutton

As soon as i open my application i have to play a video, by the time the video is being completed i have to add a UIbutton on that video, is it possible, i have searched but i could not find a link, if anybody has passed this situation, and resolved it, can u kindly say me how to do this?
The code for adding the video is :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"splash_screen"ofType:@"mp4"];         
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];  
    player.view.frame = self.view.bounds;  
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];   
    [player play];   
    [super viewDidLoad];  
}
```

Comment: [super viewDidLoad];  always call the super class's method first, This gives the super class a chance to do any set-up that you may be relying on later in your method. :)

Comment: @RIP : Yes, that's what i wanted so i have written the code for above the [super viewDidLoad];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(movieFinished) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

This will call selector "movieFinished" once movie completed, after that you can make the changes that you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer i have tried with the following code there MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];
    [player stop]; 
[self.view addSubview:newGameBtn];
the code for UIButton is done in init method, then the app is getting crashed..saying: -[UIRoundedRectButton superview]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6646120

Comment: this seems like issue at other place, are you releasing newGameBtn somewhere?

Comment: what all release statement you have used. Can you check that once more, or you can add code for that also here.

Comment: Hey, i haven't released anything and now its working fine and almost getting my required output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` notification. For [more Info](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can add observer to notify the end of the movie.

The observer can be set as follows:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                    addObserver: self
                       selector: @selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
                           name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                         object: player];
```

For more info, see the [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingVideo/UsingVideo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH3-SW1),  **Listing 2-1**  Playing full-screen movies